# Rails / Ruby - Real time screen scraping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possiable to create real time screen scraping?

Like this site: www.bog.nu

Here is some information about the site on english: http://casperfabricius.com/site/2010/11/11/launch-bog-nu/

I know about Mechanize. But I don´t see it should work with Cramp and Eventmachine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is--they'll crawl the websites they want to scrape, parse the HTML, and get the info they need.

I don't know how they've broken up the responsibilities of the app, but for example, see [this example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/sunlight_streamcongress.html) for one way you could grab info and stream it real-time. Here the info is going to an HTML5 page, but it could just as easily be stuffed in to a database and served up by a regular browser request rather than streamed.